# How can I allow an AWS user/role access to only the resources that he created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I want to create a role for a Lambda function that allows it to create/update/delete any resource, as long as that resource was also created by it. For example, it should be able to create an SQS queue and do anything with it, but it should not have access to any other SQS queues from that AWS account.

Can this be achieved using IAM policies?

I've tried to use `resourceTag` and `requestTag` conditions for this, allowing the role to create or modify a resource only if is tagged with a specific value. Unfortunately, a lot of AWS services [do not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) authorization based on tags.

Are there other options for achieving this?

Comment: No, this is not possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could create IAM policies that only allow a user to create, update, delete resources that have a particular naming scheme.  For example, you could set the policy's resource arn to have "/username*".  The user would only be able to create resources that start with their username and effect those resources.  They wouldn't be able to effect resources created that started with another users name and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to do in practice. You would have to combine the tags that you already mentioned, along with [permission boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html).

I think the best way to achieve this is to give you application its own dedicated AWS account, so that you can scope its permissions to that account, and it doesn't have the ability to impact other applications.